# How to use the Increment to show differentiability

Tags: calculus, analysis

In my book there is this proposition:

> The function f:I $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$
> if and only if the increment $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ can be written as
> $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=ah+r(h)$ with $lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0$

But how do I use this equality to show differentiability?
Taking for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
my usual way would be
to show that $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}$ exists

My idea is:
$f(x+h)-f(x_0)=\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}$ this should equal $ah+r(h)$

Now I dont know how to find the terms $a$ and $r(h)$. And is there a way to show differentiability without knowing them exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this definition it follows (dividing by $h$ and taking the limit) that $a=f'(x)$.